# Printing code via a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, global-variables

How do i print code via a function? with "echo"?

Comment: Global variables are usually a bad idea. Use dependency injection instead and you will save yourself a lot of headache down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enclose a native PHP function inside double quotes (*doing that so will render them as a normal string*). This applies to every native PHP function available.,

The **right way** is to concatenate them like this.

```
echo "with$sub = ".str_replace($sub,$letter,prev($stepsinchain));
```

#### For your clear understanding..

```
echo substr('abcdef', 1); //"prints" bcdef
echo "substr('abcdef', 1)"; //"prints" substr('abcdef', 1)
```